# Play videos in IE6 without Flash Plugin

Tags: video, embed, internet-explorer-6

I have a task to integrate a video in internet explorer 6 (WIN XP) so that I can perform certain actions (eg JavaScript). 
I know that I can embed a WMV-video because the WM-Player supports the format native, but I don´t know about solutions to controll a wmv video (jump to a specific time or get the current time).

Does somebody know about a way to embed a video in Internet Explorer 6 without installing a plugin (e.g. flash) however, with the possibility to control the video?

Cheers